# Add 50 min to the current time

Tags: javascript

I have a select field which contains option fields with hours and minutes like this:

```
<select name="" id="delyvery-hour">
  <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
  <option value="18:05">18:05</option>
  <option value="18:15">18:15</option>
  <option value="18:20">18:20</option>
  <option value="18:25">18:25</option>
  <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
  <option value="18:35">18:35</option>
  <option value="18:40">18:40</option>
  <option value="18:45">18:45</option>
  <option value="18:50">18:50</option>
  <option value="18:55">18:55</option>
  <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
  <option value="19:05">19:05</option>
  <option value="19:15">19:15</option>
  <option value="19:20">19:20</option>
  <option value="19:25">19:25</option>
  <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
  <option value="19:35">19:35</option>
  <option value="19:40">19:40</option>
  <option value="19:45">19:45</option>
  <option value="19:50">19:50</option>
  <option value="19:55">19:55</option>
  <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

I'm using jquery to detect the current time and remove the options front the select with the passed hours.

What I want to achieve is to display only the options which are 50 min ahead.

For example if now is 18:00 I need to see the option with time from 18:50 or if the current hour is 19:20 to show the options from 20:10 and etc.

Here is the example: https://codepen.io/7lifedesign/pen/dyvaxWW

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours();
document.write(time);

 $('#delyvery-hour option').filter(function(){
   return parseInt(this.value,10) < time;
 }).remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward: retrieve the current date, add 50 minutes to it, and store it in hh:mm format. Then filter your `<option>` tags to remove any option whose value is less than (string-wise, not numerically) the given hh:mm.

```js
  function pad2(n) {
    if (n < 10) {
      n = '0' + n;
    }
    return n;
  }

  var dt = new Date();
  dt.setMinutes ( dt.getMinutes() + 50 ); // 50 minutes from now
  var hhmm = pad2(dt.getHours()) + ':' + pad2(dt.getMinutes()); // e.g. 18:05

//document.write(hhmm);

   $('#delyvery-hour option').filter(function(){
     return this.value < hhmm;
   }).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name="" id="delyvery-hour">
  <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
  <option value="18:05">18:05</option>
  <option value="18:15">18:15</option>
  <option value="18:20">18:20</option>
  <option value="18:25">18:25</option>
  <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
  <option value="18:35">18:35</option>
  <option value="18:40">18:40</option>
  <option value="18:45">18:45</option>
  <option value="18:50">18:50</option>
  <option value="18:55">18:55</option>
  <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
  <option value="19:05">19:05</option>
  <option value="19:15">19:15</option>
  <option value="19:20">19:20</option>
  <option value="19:25">19:25</option>
  <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
  <option value="19:35">19:35</option>
  <option value="19:40">19:40</option>
  <option value="19:45">19:45</option>
  <option value="19:50">19:50</option>
  <option value="19:55">19:55</option>
  <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```